# Hiding Menu Options and Toolbar Items in DocuSign Recipient View using REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on customizing the appearance of the DocuSign recipient view within an embedded scenario using the REST API. My objective is to enhance the user interface by hiding specific menu options and toolbar items. Additionally, I am looking to suppress the DocuSign loading screen that appears when opening the signing URL. Could anyone please guide me on achieving these customizations?

I tried something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl4b4.png)

Create envelope api:
[image]
After using docusign focused view, I am getting the following output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6jmT.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right direction to using the new feature called "[Focused View][1]" that does exactly what you want.

The code you shared is one of the REST API calls you have to make. First, you need to create an envelope, this is your first API call.
Then you need to create a recipient view, which is the API call you're showing here.
Then you take the URL you receive in this call and put it in your HTML page with a bit of JavaScript like this:

```
-->
<br />
<h2>The document has been embedded with focused view.</h2>
<br />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />
    <title>Signing</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .docusign-agreement {
            width: 75%;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=\"docusign-agreement\" id=\"agreement\"></div>
</body>
</html>

<p><a>Continue</a></p>

<script src='https://js.docusign.com/bundle.js'></script>
<script>
    window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign('" . $integrationKey . "')
        .then((docusign) => {
            const signing = docusign.signing({
                url: '" . $url . "',
                displayFormat: 'focused',
                style: {
                    /** High-level variables that mirror our existing branding APIs. Reusing the branding name here for familiarity. */
                    branding: {
                        primaryButton: {
                            /** Background color of primary button */
                            backgroundColor: '#333',
                            /** Text color of primary button */
                            color: '#fff',
                        }
                    },
                
                    /** High-level components we allow specific overrides for */
                    signingNavigationButton: {
                        finishText: 'You have finished the document! Hooray!',
                        position: 'bottom-center'
                    }
                }
            });
        
            signing.on('ready', (event) => {
                console.log('UI is rendered');
            });
        
            signing.on('sessionEnd', (event) => {
                /** The event here denotes what caused the sessionEnd to trigger, such as signing_complete, ttl_expired etc../ **/
                console.log('sessionend', event);
                window.close();
            });
        
            signing.mount('#agreement');
        })
        .catch((ex) => {
            // Any configuration or API limits will be caught here
        });
</script>

<!--




  [1]: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/
```

Comment: How can we improve the styling of focused view, right now it is messed up.

Comment: I want to display only the 'Agree and signed' options on my PDF, but currently, I have multiple menu options such as name, last name, signature, etc. I have also included tabs while creating the envelope, but they are not functioning as expected.

Comment: You should maybe use Elastic signing if I understand your issue, this feature (not having to have at least a single tab/signing element) will be available only sometimes next year

Comment: What you want is not to have any tabs, is that right? if not - I'm not clear what is your issue

Comment: Yes, I want only one option 'Agree and signed' on my document.

Comment: And I suppose you want it RIGHT NOW? So, here is what I suggest you look into Elastic Signing using the Click API

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/how-to/embed-elastic-templates/

Comment: No, no. I don't want this; I want something as shown in the image link below.

https://images.ctfassets.net/aj9z008chlq0/4OZxPqgj6zZmVr3uQmu3mZ/eede36db7bc384bc6d99aee03256f52b/focusedViewResults.png?w=681&h=699&q=50&fm=webp

Comment: The image below has a signature tab, is that ok?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/ is what you want then

Comment: Yes, I followed this documentation, but I am not getting this kind of UI in my focuse view.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check that.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought and explained, you have to add at least one field/tag/tab/signing element. You had not added any. This capability to have an envelope without any fields will be coming out later this year, for now you cannot do this. Add a single tab, any tab you want and you'll be good.

Comment: I am adding that (see the question), but still same response.

Comment: If you follow our code example that I linked here, it works correctly, no menu. I'm not sure if that's what you are doing or you are writing your own code.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLEd9.png

I'm trying to follow the DocuSign instructions and add a single tab, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: This is not the instructions I sent you

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/

Comment: You will see that the JSON is different, and that you need to make two API calls

Comment: Yes, I am making two api calls and could you please send me the json here?

Comment: Everything is in the link I sent, I strongly suggest you download quickstart and see it working there. Just to see it can work first

Comment: How could I fix the alignment of menu options and toolbar items in the focused view.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVF9S.png

Comment: I assume you don't want this toolbar at all, is that correct?

Comment: No, I want to show the toolbar

Comment: This toolbar is not going to be there for Focused View, it's not meant for Focused View. If you want it - you have to use regular embedded signing

Comment: Ok, thank you.
Could we hide the following screen when we click a document to sign in focused view.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6jmT.png

Comment: You can turn off the Electronic Records and Signature Disclosure dialog by setting useDisclosure to false in the createEnvelope API method. (Make sure this is approved by your legal team.)